# Javascript leading commas in declarations

Tags: atom-editor

This is a formatting issue that's been bugging me. I like to use leading commas in my grouped variable declarations, ie:

`var something = true
  , anotherVar = false`

Debate about whether that's good or not, aside... I've noticed when I cut and paste this in the Atom editor it drops the leading tab /spacing so that the comma is directly under the "v" in `var` and the variable names are misaligned.

Might seem trivial but it causes my OCD to flare up. Are there any known workarounds? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Found a workaround:

Settings > Language Javascript (Package) > Uncheck **Auto Indent On Paste**

Will report back if there's any adverse consequences, so far seems to work as expected.